# update with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The code :

```
UPDATE tt_t_documents
SET t_Doc_header_ID = (SELECT
                          MIN(dh.Doc_header_ID)
                        FROM tt_t_documents td WITH (NOLOCK)
                        JOIN Doc_header dh WITH (NOLOCK)
                          ON dh.DH_doc_number = td.t_dh_doc_number
                          AND dh.DH_sub = 1
                        JOIN Pred_entry pe WITH (NOLOCK)
                          ON pe.Pred_entry_ID = dh.DH_pred_entry
                        JOIN Doc_type dt WITH (NOLOCK)
                          ON dty.Doc_type_ID = pe.PD_doc_type
                          AND dt.DT_mode = 5
                        HAVING COUNT(dh.Doc_header_ID) = 1);
```

I want to update my columns, but before that I also want to check if there is only one ID found.

The problem in this select is that I get more than one ID.

How can I write a query that updates each row and checks in the same query that there is only one id found?

Comment: First off - Read up on  (nolock), do you have a valid reason for using this? I suspect not. This can cause invalid results, please don't use it randomly on queries

Comment: `I want also check if there is only one ID found`, and what do you want to do with the result of that check?

Comment: @Milney - Far worse than unexpected results in this case. It can cause index corruption because this is an update statement. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3172/avoid-using-nolock-on-sql-server-update-and-delete-statements/

Comment: @Lamak Update if one ID found else not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you intend something like this:

```
update td 
    set t_Doc_header_ID = min_Doc_header_ID
    from tt_t_documents td join
         (select DH_doc_number, min(dh.Doc_header_ID) as min_Doc_header_ID
          from Doc_header dh join
               Pred_entry pe 
               on pe.Pred_entry_ID = dh.DH_pred_entry join
               Doc_type dt
               on dty.Doc_type_ID = pe.PD_doc_type and dt.DT_mode = 5
          where dh.DH_doc_number = td.t_dh_doc_number and dh.DH_sub = 1
          group by DH_doc_number
          having count(dh.Doc_header_ID) = 1
         ) dh
         on dh.DH_doc_number = td.t_dh_doc_number;
```

Using a `join` also means that you do not update the values where the condition does not match.  If you use a `left join`, then the values will be updated to `NULL` (if that is your intention).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I believe you are getting more than one id back with that select given that you are doing a 'min' on it and have no group by. It should be only returning the lowest value for Doc_header_id.

To do what you are asking, first, you should have some way of joining to the tt_t_documents table in the update statement (eg. where td.id == tt_t_documents.id).

Second, you could re-write it to use the sub-query in the from. Something like:

```
update 
    tt_t_documents 
set 
    t_Doc_header_ID = x.Doc_Header_id
from tt_t_documents join (
        select td.id, 
            min(dh.Doc_header_ID)
        from
            tt_t_documents  td
            join Doc_header dh
                on dh.DH_doc_number = td.t_dh_doc_number
                and dh.DH_sub = 1
            join Pred_entry pe 
                on pe.Pred_entry_ID = dh.DH_pred_entry
            join Doc_type dt 
                on dty.Doc_type_ID = pe.PD_doc_type
                and dt.DT_mode = 5
        group by td.id
        having 
            count(dh.Doc_header_ID) = 1
    ) x on tt_t_documents.id= x.id;
```

The syntax may not be perfect and I'm not sure how you want to find the doc_header_id but it would be something like this. The sub query would only return values with 1 doc_header_id). Not knowing the schema of your tables, this is as close as I can get.